# How to calculate the branching fraction of hadrons? Or good resources on chiral perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-chromodynamics, chirality, hadron-dynamics

I am wondering how I could calculate branching ratios (or any effective diagram) for various hadrons. In particular I am interested in a rare pion decay via a virtual photon:$\pi^0\to \gamma \gamma^* \to \gamma \chi {\bar{\chi}}$ where $\chi$ is some new state I introduce. This would be an effective theory of course, and I guess there would be some effective Feynman rule at the $\pi^0$ vertex?

I think this would fall in the field of chiral perturbation theory, which I do not have too much experience with. Does anyone know any good sources that I can study so I can learn how to calculate processes like this? There is a nice review by Pich $[1]$; I am going through it but it's a bit longer than I have time for right now (but please don't hesitate to send other good long resources). Naively, as I said in the paragraph above, I would expect there to be some effective Feynman rules dependent on the energy scale I am looking at, but maybe my hopes are too high with this...

Reference:

1. A. Pich, *Chiral Perturbation Theory*, [Rept. Prog. Phys. **58**, 563-610 (1995)](https://doi.org/10.1088/0034-4885/58/6/001), [arXiv:hep-ph/9502366](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9502366).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might start from Scherer's review $[1]$, which summarizes the anomaly effective vertex for the $πγγ$ coupling, in its (4.130),
$$
{e^2 \over 32 \pi^2  F_\pi} \pi^0 F\cdot \tilde F.
$$
Note I am using  Scherer's convention for the pion decay constant, $F_\pi \sim 92$MeV; this is half of Witten's.

You indicate your have introduced a $\gamma \bar \chi \chi$ coupling, which only you know, but your amplitude  merely involves the above vertex and yours, and a photon propagator. You should be able to take it from there.

Reference:

1. S. Scherer, *Introduction to Chiral Perturbation Theory*, [arXiv:hep-ph/0210398](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210398).

Comment: Hi @Cosmas Zachos , had a quick question. I am having some confusion on the convention value for $f_{\pi}$; in the convention you wrote in your answer above, what value does this assume?

Comment: I'll use Scerer's in an edit. Recall *n* =3, the number of colors.